# How to select with AVD you want use to emulate a Android Phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

until now i have one AVD, android 1.5 google Apis 3 (because i use googlemaps on my app), to emulate my apps.

now i need to use a new AVD, android 1.5 but with SD card, and i created it with the AVD manager of eclipse.

ok, it's created.... but ¿how can i launch my app with that AVD?? i only can launch it with the old AVD, and i dont know how to do the change of AVD.

if i put Run Configurations, i only can see my old AVD, i can't see any other. Also if i put manual, i only can see my old AVD, not the new. And yes, it's created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

run menu -> run configurations -> second tab "target".

You can choose your new one, or set it to "Manual"

Comment: then choose automatic, choose the manager and create a new one?

Comment: ok solved, it is because my project is Google Apis 1.5, and not Android 1.5, then i have to create the new ADV as google apis, and not as android 1.5

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to start the AVD with the Android SDK manager. Your IDE should pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As your application is using Google Map Api ,so your newly created AVD(dont know wheather is it using Google Map Api or not) is not launching.
Try to create a new AVD with sdcard,then launch the AVD(newly created) then launch the application